# Regulator of an algebraic number field and regulator of units.

Tags: number-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field. I would like to know why in totally real fields regulator is at most equal to regulator of a set of $n-1$ independent units. What happens in the case of $K$ not being totally real?